# Regex to select everything a replace with a word

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have lots of diffrent lines with numbers, symbols and words, i need them all replaced with a word of my choosing, i tried `^.(.)` but it didnt work

```
james!@
fire11
exampleexample
```

I need them to become any word i put in replace with, so for example

```
Football 
Football
football
```

The regex would need to target everything inside the file, not just words, but symbols and numbers, any help is appreciated

Comment: So with multiline option set: `.*` replace with `Football`? I'm confused.

Comment: Sounds like you need to learn more.  your regex is not close.

Comment: Please see [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Comment: So the regex should find exactly one match per file — the entire file? Or do you not want whitespace (spaces? newlines?) in the match?

Comment: ctwheels method worked perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
(.*)$
```

Replace with it

```
Football
```